# iOS Twin Push SDK Lib showNotification not fired

Tags: ios, swift

I am using TwinPushSDK to receive notifications using Swift language.

http://developers.twinpush.com/developers/ios?class=sidebar-header#twinpush-sdk-library

Everything it's working fine but I need to receive the event when the notification is shown.

My AppDelegate extends TwinPushManagerDelegate and as it's explained in the document I have to implement showNotification

`From SDK`
Once you have that controller, you have to override the default behavior to stop TwinPush from showing the default viewer. To achieve it, simply implement the method showNotification, declared in TwinPushManagerDelegate, in your application delegate and show your view controller. For example:

This is My AppDelegate

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelate, TwinPushManagerDelegate{


....
....
....

   // Swift
   // MARK: TwinPushManagerDelegate
   func showNotification(notification: TPNotification!) {
      // Only show content viewer for rich notifications
      doWhatever()
   }

}
```

http://developers.twinpush.com/developers/ios?class=sidebar-header#custom-rich-notification-viewer

This is never fired and I need to control it, I can stop it inside the lib class but not in my delegate

am I missing something?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Is your `AppDelegate` class implemented in Objective-C or Swift? Can you share the method signature to check if it's correct?

Comment: My AppDelegete is in Swift and TwinPush ManagerDelegate is in Obj-C. 

https://github.com/TwinPush/ios-sdk/blob/master/TwinPushSDK/Classes/TwinPushManager.h

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The automatic Swift signature generated from Objective-C now doesn't include parameter names in the method name, try with this signature:

```
func show(_ notification: TPNotification!) {
    doWhatever()
}
```

XCode should be able to auto-complete with the correct signatures in case any other has changed.